# Storing List<string> into isolated storage retuns null when app restarted

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I am storing object of type `List<string>` in the Isolated Storage. My problem is when I close the app and relaunch it later, and try to retrieve `List<string>`, it returns null.

All other object such as `string`, `bool`, `int`, `Dictionary<string, bool>` etc retain their values except the `List<string>` object.

```
  public List<string> BuddyGroupsSetting
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValueOrDefault<List<string>>(BuddyGroupsKeyName, BuddyGroupsDefault);
        }
        set
        {
            AddOrUpdateValue(BuddyGroupsKeyName, value);
            Save();
        }
    }
```

I've checked my code there's no command to clear the list anywhere. What am I missing?

Comment: The code shown isn't really going to allow us to help you.  The setter allows null, so there is the possibility that code is setting it to null.  You haven't shown us the code that saves/loads the list from storage.

Comment: Thanks Matt, found out setter was never called causing the unsaved value. I explain in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out. Simple mistake.. Instead of setting a value directly to the 'BuddyGroupsSetting` property, I mistakenly add an item using

```
BuddyGroupsSetting.Add(item)
```

So `set` was never actually called! To correct this I created a private field

```
private List<string> buddyGroupsSetting = new List<string>();
```

Then use this field to set the value

```
buddyGroupsSetting = BuddyGroupsSetting
```

Comment: If you found a solution, mark your own answer as Accepted!